# Site is offline message seems Sketchy

Tags: bug, chat, design, 500-server-error

Was trying to get to the Teacher's Lounge when I got this:

[image]

This page seems to be local to chat.SE; it happened when trying to access UX today as well. The design's still Sketchy instead of Grainy.

Comment: The "site down" message for beta sites is also Sketchy.